# Conjugation patterns for u-dropping verbs

Tags: verbs, pattern

I was given a table by my book:

[image]

The pattern I spotted is, except for u-dropping verbs ending in つ, we have that every verb preserves its consonant (s, k, g, m, n, b, w or r) when conjugated. Thus, this simplifies to the following pattern: for masu form, consonant plus imasu and, for nai form, consonant plus nai. For example, to conjugate およぐ (oyogu) in masu form we have to first drop the u vowel because it's a u-dropping verb, then we need to make sure we are able to adjunct imasu while preserving the consonant g. The only syllable that allow us to do this is ぎ (gi), so we have およぎます (oyogimasu). Analogously, the same method can be used to conjugate the verb to nai form. Like always, there are exceptions. Consider the verb ある (exist), which patterns as a u-dropping verb until it is conjugated in nai form. That is, ない. Another example is きる (wear), whose nai form is きない instead of きらない if we were to use the method above. However, there is another verb whose dictionary form is also きる (cut), but its nai form is きらない.

My question is: is it advisible to use this pattern?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  It is advisable, if you want to be understood and strive for a more native sound, to use the appropriate forms, as reflected in your table.  If you want to say "I only wear the blue shirts" then you'll want to say あおいシャーツしかきない.　If you say あおいシャーツしかきらない, then you're saying "I only cut the blue shirts."  Maybe I'm missing your point.  If so, please set me right.

Comment: @A.Ellet I just want to verify if the pattern I've spotted is of use instead of learning off by heart the table as the author of the book suggested and, as I pointed out, there are exceptions to the this pattern but, for the most part, it seems viable.

Comment: These are all standard forms that should be learned so that you can use them without even thinking about them (just as you don't have think about inflecting verbs in English *sing/sang/sung/singing*, *read/read/read/reading*, *talk/talked/talked/talking*, *go/went/gone/going*).  You'll not be wasting time or filling your brain in useless forms.  These are all used in everyday speech quite regularly.

Comment: @A.Ellet The pattern I suggested is simple and it seems that it works.

Comment: Verbs that end in つ don't follow a different pattern. The romaji we use as English speakers makes it looks different I guess, but the core pattern is the same for all of the types.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear what your rule exactly says.  But that may just be me.  I'm going to suggest however that you hold off on your *general rules* and just learn these conjugations by consonantal endings (-k,-g,-s,-t,-n,-m,-b,-r) or whether the stem ends in *e* or *i* after removing *ru*.  At some point, you will be learning how to form the past tense of these verbs and you might find this throws your thinking.  Examples are: the past tense of およぐ (swim) is およいだ; past tense of とぶ  (jump) is とんだ; past tense of すむ (live) is すんだ.  Rest assured, these do have their own internal logic.

Comment: I feel like this is a matter of opinion.  The pattern may work and help some people learn, but it may be confusing and unhelpful to others.  Everyone learns in their own way, so I don't think one can make a general objective statement whether this pattern is advisable or not.

Comment: @A.Ellet Yes, I've worked on past tenses. I know they behave differently. Same applies to the **te** form, or continuing form, of a verb. Should I then just learn the conjugations off by heart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, another name for u-verb is "consonant-stem verb", which means the last consonant before the u-vowel will be preserved, and the last u will be changed to a/i/e/o. For example, かく *kaku* can conjugate like *ka**k**anai*, *ka**k**imasu*, *ka**k**e*, and *ka**k**ō*. This table basically shows most Japanese verbs are very regular and easy to remember.

By the way, 着る【きる】 meaning "to wear" is a **regular** ru-verb (aka vowel-stem or ichidan verb). There is nothing exceptional. You just have to remember the verb type; one きる is a regular ru-verb and the other きる is a regular u-verb.